# What does the "Stationery Pad" option do?

Tags: macos, finder, uti

Under the `General` section of a file's File Info, there is a checkbox for `Stationery Pad` and `Locked`. The `Locked` option is pretty straightforward, but what does `Stationery Pad` do?

[image]

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what I should tag this, so if anybody has a better suggestion, feel free to change it.

Comment: Funnily enough, if I translate the text used by that option in the Finnish OS X to English, it's roughly "Work template". I think even just "template" would describe the option better than "stationery pad"

Comment: This is a really nice OS feature. Just discovered its use. No need for complex /template folders and duplicate files everywhere. Just a master for each type and copies made as needed. Surprised not to hear of this more.

Comment: Just for a reference, this question is answered at http://superuser.com/questions/96245/what-is-the-stationery-pad-setting-in-os-x-finder

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Basically, it tells an app opening the file to open a copy.

You do this on files that you want to use like templates. Since the app is given a copy, you'll never accidentally change the original.

Basically, it automatically copies the file into its original location (as '*name* copy') and lets you work on the copy.